Replace individual function definition based on definitions in toolchain file
I am making a library which will define a number of functions. There will be a default version of each function, and then the user may provide a file containing alternative definitions of each function, optimized for a certain hardware target.
I have a header file eg operations.h:
//operations.h

#ifndef OPERATIONS_H
#define OPERATIONS_H

#define BASE_OPERATION_1
int operation_1(int a, int b);
#define BASE_OPERATION_2
int operation_2(int a, int b);

#endif

Then the default implementations in a source file:
//base/operations.c

#ifdef BASE_OPERATION_1
int op_1(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
#endif 

#ifdef BASE_OPERATION_2
int op_2(int a, int b)
{
    return 2 * (a + b);
}
#endif 

I then have custom implementations in a separate source file. There may not be a replacement for every function.
// custom/operations.c

#ifdef CUSTOM_OPERATION_2
#undef BASE_OPERATION_2
int op_2(int a, int b)
{
    return 3 * (a + b);
}
#endif 

Then in a toolchain file I can do
set(CUSTOM_SOURCES custom/operations.c)
add_definitions( -DCUSTOM_OPERATION_2 )


The above solution results in a "duplicate symbol" error. I think because the preprocessor does not see both .c files at the same time, and so the undef does not achieve the behaviour I want. They are in different translation units so the undef is never seen when compiling the base file.
Can anyone tell me a way to get this behavior?

Is this "library" supposed to be a bunch of C file the user of said library can add to their project or do you want to create a library file holding all the functions? In latter case, you need to keep in mind that the library file will already be done when the user compiles the own files. You cannot change content of the library then.

It is intended to be built by the user. They will have access to the source code and can add their custom operations. From there they will build the library and use it in another project. At this point it will be customized for their hardware target.

To solve your problem, remove all preprocessor
directives concerning BASE_OPERATION_N and rewrite source files like so:
//operations.h

#ifndef OPERATIONS_H
#define OPERATIONS_H

int op_1(int a, int b);
int op_2(int a, int b);

#endif

//base/operations.c

#include <operations.h>

#ifndef CUSTOM_OP_1
int op_1(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
#endif 

#ifndef CUSTOM_OP_2
int op_2(int a, int b)
{
    return 2 * (a + b);
}
#endif 

// custom/operations.c

#ifdef CUSTOM_OP_2
int op_2(int a, int b)
{
    return 3 * (a + b);
}
#endif

With this, -DCUSTOM_OP_2 suffices to disable compilation of base op_2 and
enable the compilation of custom op_2. Conversely the absence of -DCUSTOM_OP_2
suffices to disable the compilation of custom op_2 and enable the compilation
of base op_2.
Here's a demo. My CMake project is:
$ tree
.
├── base
│   └── operations.c
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── config.cmake
├── custom
│   └── operations.c
├── operations.h
└── test.c

cmake.config is my toolchain file. It doesn't need to exist for the
default build. I'm building a test program as well as the library to prove this works. For the
same purpose I'm putting some printfs in the sources:
$ cat base/operations.c 
//base/operations.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <operations.h>

#ifndef CUSTOM_OP_1
int op_1(int a, int b)
{
    printf("%s_%s\n","Base",__func__);
    return a + b;
}
#endif 

#ifndef CUSTOM_OP_2
int op_2(int a, int b)
{
    printf("%s_%s\n","Base",__func__);
    return 2 * (a + b);
}
#endif

$ cat custom/operations.c 
// custom/operations.c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef CUSTOM_OP_1
int op_1(int a, int b)
{
    printf("%s_%s\n","Custom",__func__);
    return 3 * (a + b);
}
#endif

#ifdef CUSTOM_OP_2
int op_2(int a, int b)
{
    printf("%s_%s\n","Custom",__func__);
    return 3 * (a + b);
}
#endif

My CMakeLists.txt is:
$ cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(operations)

set(BASE_SOURCES ./base/operations.c)
set(SOURCES ${BASE_SOURCES} ${CUSTOM_SOURCES})
include_directories(./)

add_library(
  operations
  ${SOURCES}
)

add_executable(
    test
    test.c)
    
target_link_libraries(test operations)

The default build goes:
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build
$ make
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/operations.dir/base/operations.c.o
[ 50%] Linking C static library liboperations.a
[ 50%] Built target operations
[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable test
[100%] Built target test

And the program runs:
$ ./test
Base_op_1
Base_op_2

Now here's my toolchain file v. 1:
$ cd ..
$ cat config.cmake 
set(CUSTOM_SOURCES ./custom/operations.c)
add_compile_options(-DCUSTOM_OP_2)

I'm disabling base op_2, enabling custom op_2
Zap and regenerate the build system:
$ cd build
$ rm -fr *
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=config.cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build

Rebuild and test:
$ make && ./test
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/operations.dir/base/operations.c.o
[ 40%] Building C object CMakeFiles/operations.dir/custom/operations.c.o
[ 60%] Linking C static library liboperations.a
[ 60%] Built target operations
[ 80%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable test
[100%] Built target test
Base_op_1
Custom_op_2

There's the custom op_2.
Now I'd like to revert to base op_2 and enable custom op_1. The tool chain file for that is v.2:
$ cd ..
$ cat config.cmake 
set(CUSTOM_SOURCES ./custom/operations.c)
add_compile_options(-DCUSTOM_OP_1)

Don't need to regenerate the build system now. I can do:
$ cd build
$ make
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/operations.dir/base/operations.c.o
[ 40%] Building C object CMakeFiles/operations.dir/custom/operations.c.o
[ 60%] Linking C static library liboperations.a
[ 60%] Built target operations
[ 80%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable test
[100%] Built target test
$ ./test
Custom_op_1
Base_op_2

There's the custom op_1.

Thank you for this answer. This works perfectly for me with gcc but I get a linker relocation error (concerning some unrelated function) with clang. This goes away if I compile with -flto. Is something here against some standard?

@confusedandsad Relocation errors usually arise from attempting to
link non-position-independent object files into a
shared library, which demands PIC code. Such non-PIC
object files have usually been extracted from a static
lirary input to the linkage of the shared library, in
which case you need to rebuild the static library,
recompiling all the object files with compiler option
-fPIC.

@confusedandsad If this does not help, ask a new question, providing
a minimal reproducible example,
or if that is impossible then a complete vebatim build log
of the failing linkage command.

Could it be about the order of compilation of these source files? If base one gets compiled first, it would be compiled using BASE_OPERATION_2 as defined, which would result in duplicate symbol.
Can you try changing your operations.h like below for both op1 and op2 and try again:
#ifndef CUSTOM_OPERATION_2
#define BASE_OPERATION_2
#endif 


I have tried this using normal Make instead of Cmake and had the same problem as yours, and the problem was resolved with the change i proposed, fyi.

Thanks for trying this. The problem with this approach is that I do not know if the user of the library will provide custom implementations or not, or they may provide many. For this reason I am unable to reference any custom implementation from the base header file. There will not only be "CUSTOM_OPERATION" but potentially TARGET1_OPERATION ... TARGET999_OPERATION, so I cannot check for them all in this header.

Actually I may be wrong, they can only have one custom implementation at a time. So it may be OK to call it "CUSTOM"

In this case I suppose I do not need the "BASE_OPERATION_N" flag at all, and I can just wrap the base implementation in an "#ifndef CUSTOM_OPERATION_N"

Part of the answer should go into a comment instead of an answer. And no, if you only change the order of compilation, the result will not change at all as the macros from one C file are not visible in another C file.

I think they would either be defined in a header file or globally visible as they are given as a compilation flag (-D)

For some reason doing what I describe results in the library only compiling when -flto is present. Otherwise I get a relocation error with the linker
